# Indented here document causes a syntax error

Tags: shell-script, ksh, whitespace, here-document

I have the following code fragment in my shell script and have a bug that I can't seem to pin down a reason for despite some research.
When I run the code as below the script exits with a message saying

```
./my_script.sh:  line 53: syntax error at line 61: `<<' unmatched
```

I've used `set -x` and can see that all is fine up until the error (I only set variables anyway).
For some reason simply removing the spaces (and they are spaces not non-display characters) from before the `eot` allows it to work.
It leaves my xml looking a bit mis-aligned but functional. 
Does anyone know why this happens as I dislike things like this that I can't explain and I would like my xml to look pretty as well.

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
# ... various environment variables set here ...

clean_files()          # line 53
{
    # Clear up the intermediate files
    mv $datafile $ARCHIVE_DIR/$(basename $datafile).$$
}

xmlfile_header()
{                      # line 60
        cat <<- eot
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
                <ppllist>
        eot  
}

# ... more stuff ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `<<- word` here-doc form requires that **only tab characters** can appear before `word`. You can't use spaces, must be tabs.

ref: http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Input/Output

Comment: Thanks for that link glenn. I've been hunting for an explanation on and off all day to no avail.